# How to add rule to block program like chrome or firefox from accessing any Ip address using Window firewall or netsh advfirewall-C#?

Tags: c#, networking, ip, firewall

I want to add a rule using netsh advfirewall firewall to block any programs like chrome or firefox from accesing specific Ips?**Would appreciate your help!!!**

This is the code I tried but it did'nt work.Please guide me.

```
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=Block inbound traffic from 192.168.0.2 over TCP port 4000 dir=in action=block program=C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/Firefox.exe enable=yes protocol=TCP remoteip=192.168.0.2 profile=domain,private,public";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the netsh stuff (and don't know why you are calling this from C#), but the most obvious error of the netsh call is the missing quoting of spaces in the `program=C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/Firefox.exe` argument. As spaces are used as argument separators, it is parsed as three separate arguments, `program=c:/Program` and `Files/Mozilla` and `Firefox/Firefox.exe`. You can see the most simple fix in the [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments) description: Add escaped quotation marks around the path, i.e. `"... program=\"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/Firefox.exe\" ..."`.

Other recommendations:

- AFAICS, you don't need `cmd.exe` to call `netsh`, so you could simply call netsh.exe
- Why are you using forward slashes in the path? It works with most stuff, but not with all, so I would recommend using backslashes `\` as this is the Windows default path separator.
- Rather than giving all arguments in a single string `Arguments` (and risking to stumble over subtleties like quoting), I would recommend `ArgumentList`.

In the end, it would look like this:

```
  var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
  {
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "netsh",
    ArgumentList =
    {
      "advfirewall", "firewall",
      "add", "rule", "name=Block", "inbound", "traffic",
      "from", "192.168.0.2", "over", "TCP", "port", "4000", "dir=in", "action=block",
      @"program=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe",
      "enable=yes",
      "protocol=TCP",
      "remoteip=192.168.0.2",
      "profile=domain,private,public",
    },
    Verb = "runas",
  };
  Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks man for replying I got your point but I can't use ArgumentList as it's showing error ProcessStartinfo does not contains defination of "ArgumentList",Actually I have multiple network adapters on my Windows  system.I wanted firefox or chrome to use a specific adapters Hence I tried above stuff by blocking ip  but I failed in making my browsers accessing specific networkadapter. And this have to be done programmingly.